# I don't understand why this code is throwing an Error?

Tags: mysql, syntax-error

I'm running the following code in MySQL Workbench:

```
CREATE TABLE beer_type ( -- create beer table
type_id INTEGER NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY, -- PK "type_id"
beer_name VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL,
beer_type VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL,
beer_id INTEGER NOT NULL,
FOREIGN KEY (beer_id) REFERENCES beer (beer_id));
```

I'm getting:

```
0   5   21:27:10    CREATE TABLE beer_type ( -- create beer table   Error Code: 1064. You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '' at line 1    0.000 sec
```

I'm new to SQL so this is a bit confusing to me and my professor isn't the best of help...
Any way anyone can help would be greatly appreciated!!

Comment: [I can't reproduce](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/8N6kpCVMor5diL1crRouCz/0)

Comment: Is there at least one space after `--`?

Comment: There is one space after the --

Comment: @Snare_Dragon i think there's a difference between what you are sharing, and how you are actually running the query

Answer (score 0):

Copy this and paste :

```
CREATE TABLE beer_type (
type_id INTEGER NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
beer_name VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL,
beer_type VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL,
beer_id INTEGER NOT NULL,
FOREIGN KEY (beer_id) REFERENCES beer (beer_id));
```

Comment: It still throws a 1064 error. I'm assuming there might be a new update but I'm unsure...